# How is a function a value but a method id not?

Tags: scala

Why are functions values but methods are not, or what makes a function a value in particular? What would allow me to decipher that methods do not contain that characteristic?

Comment: In Scala, function objects that look like `A => B` or `(A, B) => C` are really just syntactic sugar for objects of type `Function1[A, B]` or `Function2[A, B, C]`, etc.

Comment: Short answer, yes because. Longer answer, because that is what the language specs say. Is there a reason for being like that, I would guess to ease the Java Interop or simplify the implementation. However, it may be just because Martin wanted it to be like that.

Answer (score 3):

Scala is an object-oriented language. In object-oriented languages, every value is an object, and every object is a value.

Methods are bound to objects. It is awkward to have methods at the same time be a building block of objects and be objects themselves. It is easier to have them not be objects.

A function in Scala is, in some sense, just an object with an `apply` method. If there is no method named `foo` in scope, then [`foo()` is simply syntactic sugar for `foo.apply()`](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#function-applications). So, functions are values because they are objects.

While *any* object that has an `apply` method can be called as if it were a function, when we talk about "functions" in Scala, we usually mean something more specific: an instance of one of the [`FunctionN`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/?search=function) traits such as [`Function2[-T1, -T2, +R]`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function2.html). In particular, the *function literal syntax*

```scala
val add = (a: Int, b: Int) => a + b
```

[is syntactic sugar for](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#anonymous-functions)

```scala
val add = new Function2[Int, Int, Int] {
  override def apply(a: Int, b: Int) = a + b
}
```

And the [*function type*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#function-types)

```scala
type F = (Int, String, Long) => Boolean
```

is syntactic sugar for

```scala
type F = Function3[Int, String, Long, Boolean]
```

[[Scastie link]](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/1GQfj4OPQ0GCWrZdL3Z40Q.js)

where each of the `FunctionN` traits is defined like this:

```scala
package scala

trait Function0[+R] {
  def apply: R
  override def toString = "<function>"
}

trait Function1[-T, +R] {
  def apply(x: T): R
  override def toString = "<function>"
}

trait Function2[-T1, -T2, +R] {
  def apply(x1: T1, x2: T2): R
  override def toString = "<function>"
}

trait Function3[-T1, -T2, -T3, +R] {
  def apply(x1: T1, x2: T2, x3: T3): R
  override def toString = "<function>"
}
```

and so on.

It is possible to [convert a method into a function value](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#method-values) using [*η-expansion*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#eta-expansion-section). This can be done explicitly using a trailing underscore:

```scala
val f = println _
```

or in some cases, when it is clear that a function value is required, even by just using the bare name of the method:

```scala
val it = Iterable(1, 2, 3)

it.foreach(println)
```

[[Scastie link]](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/1GQfj4OPQ0GCWrZdL3Z40Q.js)

Note that this is not much different from other languages. In Java, C#, and Ruby, for example, it is the same thing: methods are defined as part of classes (or structs in C# and modules in Ruby) and are bound to objects, but aren't objects themselves. Instead, you have a separate notion of a function (instance of a SAM interface / functional interface in Java, `Action` or `Func` in C#, `Proc` in Ruby), which *is* an object.

In Ruby, you can create a proxy object for a method that is bound to an object which has the same interface as `Proc`.

Other languages make different choices, i.e. in ECMAScript and Python, methods *are* objects / values, but they are not as tightly bound to objects as they are in Scala, Java, C#, and Ruby. Instead, methods are basically normal functions that are assigned to fields of the object.

Answer (score 2):

One of the defining characteristics of a value is that it can be assigned to a variable. A method, technically speaking, cannot be assigned to a variable, for example

```
def m(i: Int): Int = i + 1
val f = m // error
```

However there is a process called *eta expansion* that converts a method to a function *value*. In Scala 2, we can trigger it by providing type ascription to a variable

```
val f: Int => Int = m
```

or by using underscore `_`

```
val f = m _
```

However this restriction has been lifted in Scala 3 (Dotty) which now provides [automatic eta expansion](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/changed-features/eta-expansion-spec.html) so the following compiles successfully

```
scala> def f(i: Int): Int = i + 1
     | val x = f
def f(i: Int): Int
val x: Int => Int = Lambda$1218/158882051@62cf6a84
```